# undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass for Active Storage migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I run into an issue after trying to reset my local database.

To rebuild my database I run:
rake *db:drop db:create*

But when i Try to migrate the database with the *rake db:migrate* command i run into the following issue with an old Active Storage migration file.

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
```

undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

```
  resolve(config.fetch(:service)).build(
                ^^^^^^
```

**The migration file currently looks like this:**

```
class AddServiceNameToActiveStorageBlobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    unless column_exists?(:active_storage_blobs, :service_name)
      add_column :active_storage_blobs, :service_name, :string

      if (configured_service = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.name)
        ActiveStorage::Blob.unscoped.update_all(service_name: configured_service)
      end

      change_column :active_storage_blobs, :service_name, :string
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :active_storage_blobs, :service_name
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

My current version of Ruby and Rails is 7.0.0

**Edit:**

My stack trace looks like this:

NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

```
  resolve(config.fetch(:service)).build(
                ^^^^^^
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/lib/active_storage/service/configurator.rb:17:in `build'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/lib/active_storage/service/registry.rb:13:in `block in fetch'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/lib/active_storage/service/registry.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/lib/active_storage/service/registry.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:155:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:82:in `class_eval'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:82:in `block in execute_hook'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `with_execution_control'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:77:in `execute_hook'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:63:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `each'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activestorage-7.0.3.1/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:410:in `<main>'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `require'
/Users/../groundhop/db/migrate/20201209233133_add_service_name_to_active_storage_blobs.active_storage.rb:7:in `up'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:873:in `public_send'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:873:in `exec_migration'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:854:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `measure'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:853:in `block in migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:215:in `with_connection'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:852:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/strong_migrations-0.7.9/lib/strong_migrations/migration.rb:5:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1046:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1360:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:316:in `transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1411:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1359:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1333:in `each'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1333:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1282:in `block in migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1432:in `block in with_advisory_lock'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:215:in `with_connection'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1447:in `with_advisory_lock_connection'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1428:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1282:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1117:in `up'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1092:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:262:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/strong_migrations-0.7.9/lib/strong_migrations/database_tasks.rb:5:in `migrate'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.3.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/rake:25:in `load'
/Users/../.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/rake:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The issue here isn't explained by this migration. Look at the stack trace and see where the error is actually occuring. http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I can't still figure out what is wrong. I posted the stack trace in the question here on top.